# How to hide Particular directories in QFileSytemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel, qmodelindex

I have a `QFileSystemModel` which is use as a model in `QTreeView` . This work fine now I have names of some directories. Which I want to hide in `QTreeview`.

```
QString strCompleteDirectoryPath = "/Volumes/";
QTreeView *SourceTreeView = new QTreeView;
QSize ItemSize(20,20);
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel();
model->setNameFilterDisables(false);
model->setRootPath(strCompleteDirectoryPath);
model->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Hidden);
model->setNameFilters(QStringList("samplefolder"));
SourceTreeView->setModel(model);
SourceTreeView->setRootIndex(model->index(strCompleteDirectoryPath));
SourceTreeView->header()->resizeSection(0,350);
SourceTreeView->setIconSize(ItemSize);
```

I want to hide `"samplefolder"` in `"/Volumes"` directory. I use both strings `"samplefolder"`  and `"/Volumes/samplefolder"` in `setNameFilters()` one by one to check my filter. But it does not work for me.

So kindly tell me how could I hide this because I dont want to show it in my `QTreeView`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `QSortFilterProxyModel` for this. Example:

```
QString strCompleteDirectoryPath = "/Volumes/";

QTreeView *SourceTreeView = new QTreeView;

QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel(SourceTreeView);
model->setRootPath(strCompleteDirectoryPath);
model->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Hidden);

QSortFilterProxyModel* filter = new QSortFilterProxyModel(model);
filter->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp("^((?!samplefolder).)*$", Qt::CaseInsensitive));

SourceTreeView->setModel(filter);
```

Comment: Not working for me. When I set SourceTreeView->setModel(filter);  . SourceTreeView goes blank. It does not display any item.